# Why doesn't Splashtop Streamer load?

Tags: package-management, remote-access, streaming

I just installed Splashtop Streamer from Ubuntu Software Center. It installed without any errors, but it's not loading up when I try to start it. I'm using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

It might not be the best way, but it worked for me.

It needs **Crypto.Cipher** module. I got it from [synaptic [image: Install synaptic]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/synaptic) in [python-crypto [image: Install python-crypto]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/python-crypto) package, installed and now it works.